# Bootstrap carousel: Measure time that an image is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

does anyone know how to measure the time that an image in an Bootstarp 5 carousel (see below) is visible for the user? The idea is to measure the time that the user is looking at a specific image (e.g. image of a product) in the carousel.

f.e. the time in milliseconds that the image "image_1" is visible (open).

Many thanks,

`````
 ````
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="image_1">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="image_2">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="image_3">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    ````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```js
var intervalTime = 100;
var carousel = document.getElementById('carouselExampleControls')
var timesMilliseconds = {
  0: 0
};
var currentSlideIndex = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (timesMilliseconds.hasOwnProperty(currentSlideIndex)) {
    timesMilliseconds[currentSlideIndex] += intervalTime;
  } else {
    timesMilliseconds[currentSlideIndex] = intervalTime;
  }
}, intervalTime);

carousel.addEventListener('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
  var currentIndex = currentSlideIndex.toString();
  var currentTotalTime = timesMilliseconds[currentSlideIndex].toString();
    console.log('Looked at slide ' + currentIndex + ' for a total of ' + currentTotalTime + ' ms');

  currentSlideIndex = event.to;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/412nu3dy/2/